# How to trim an Aloe that grew too tall

Tags: houseplants, pruning, aloe

I have an Aloe that has thrived, and has grown to be too tall for its own body weight.

How should I trim this lovely plant.

[Propped up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnbDN.jpg) 
[image]

[image: droopy]

Comment: Hmm. Have you considered staking it?

Comment: I have been stacking it. but I worry about how high it will get.   I wondered if it should have the center trimmed out.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure, and the stuff I see in searches looks confusing. Plenty of information, but rather ambiguous, so far. I wonder if twisting the top off would make new branches grow lower down, as happens when pruning the top off a chile pepper or such (or if it would more likely kill it). Hopefully you'll get an answer to your question soon!

Comment: Ohooo..that's sure one  soooo happy happy plant :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't normally propagate Aloe via cuttings. [Opinion from a gardening site](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-propagate-aloe-vera-5087447)

> There are different ways to propagate your aloe vera houseplant. It can be from offshoots called “pups”, by germinating seeds, or from leaf cuttings. Propagating from pups is the easiest method and the one with the highest success rate. If you try to propagate aloe vera from a cutting placed in water, it will rot before it grows roots. The chances of the cutting rooting in potting soil are much better but require patience. For instant gratification (and new plants), pups are your best bet.

[Here is another opinion](https://www.gardeningchannel.com/can-you-grow-aloe-vera-from-a-cutting/)

> Yes, aloe vera can be propagated from a cutting. However, it’s not the most common way of propagation because it doesn’t produce the best results.

So, I would suggest that you chop the centre off and discard.  And start looking for pups to plant separately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is an Aloe vera or a Haworthia as they look similar and are closely related.  Aloe plants are [best propagated by division](https://laidbackgardener.blog/2017/11/15/garden-myth-growing-aloes-from-leaf-cuttings/) as propagating from leaves or segments of leaves will not work.

If this is a Haworthia there are [multiple ways](https://www.haworthia.com/leaf-propagation/) to propagate this plant:

- twist the part of the plant that is leaning at a point low on the stem and separate
- take the cutting and recut at the base to ensure a flat cut and let it sit on the window until the callous forms at the cut
- after a few weeks put it in soil and water

Alternately you can propagate from a leaf with the same method:

- separate from stem
- let dry
- plant in soil with full sun